# best practice for django application server on EC2

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, virtualenv, uwsgi

I'm woking on deploying a Django app on specific EC2 server. The django stack is composed of mainly Nginx + Django + Virtual Env + uWSGI + external NFS for storing log. For such deployment,

1. Considering this can be a big website with relatively high traffic, which instance type to use? any general strategy to adopt?
2. For configuration wise, what need to be aware of?

Comment: 'this can be a big website with relatively high traffic': what do you mean by this? What sort of traffic are you talking? Is it read/write or mainly read? etc. there needs to be a lot more information if this can be answered ...

Comment: Based on what I can foresee the application is a new mobile card game which may have 10-100 thousand DAU when it's released to market, the growth speed depends. I call it big just by comparing to small website like personal blog site or small e-commerce site.